# dag_id could not be found: dag_id. Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse after upgrading airflow from 1.7.3 to 1.10.1

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I upgraded the airflow version from 1.7.3 to 1.10.1. After up-gradation of the scheduler, webserver and workers, the dags have stopped working showing below error on scheduler-

Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse.

I have not made any changes to the config. While investigating the issue the scheduler logs shows the issue. Earlier the scheduler run the task as -

Adding to queue: `airflow run <dag_id> <task_id> <execution_date> --local -sd DAGS_FOLDER/<dag_filename.py>`

While now it is running with absolute path -

Adding to queue: `airflow run <dag_id> <task_id> <execution_date> --local -sd /<PATH_TO_DAGS_FOLDER>/<dag_filename.py>`

`PATH_TO_DAGS_FOLDER` is like `/home/<user>/Airflow/dags...`

which is same as what it is pushing it to workers by since worker is running on some other user it is not able to find the dag location specified.

I am not sure how to tell the worker to look in it's own airflow home dir and not the scheduler one?

I am using `mysql` as backend and `rabbitmq` for message passing.

Comment: were you able to solve? if so how?